# How do I calculate the elapsed time of an event in Java?

Tags: java, time, timer, clock

What's a simple/easy way to access the system clock using Java, so that I can calculate the elapsed time of an event?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I would avoid using [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) for measuring elapsed time. [`currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) returns the 'wall-clock' time, which may change (eg: daylight savings, admin user changing the clock) and skew your interval measurements.

[`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--), on the other hand, returns the number of nanoseconds since 'some reference point' (eg, JVM start up), and would therefore not be susceptible to system clock changes.

Comment: I don't think daylight savings time affects currentTimeMillis().  It'd defined in terms of UTC.

Comment: @Shiny: Good point on UTC - I didn't realise that. I think the main point of my response stands though, ie, currentTimeMillis() is skewed by wall-clock changes. NTP updates are another possible source of problems with currentTimeMillis().

Comment: Is System.nanoTime() resistant to CPU frequency changes too?

Comment: @kd304, I'm sure it is; it should also be robust to the computer hibernating and waking up. If it isn't, it's a bug.

Comment: See a little more detail on this in my answer to a different instance of this question which was closed as a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770010/how-do-i-measure-time-elapsed-in-java/1776053#1776053

Answer (score 27):

This is some sample code.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Run some code;
long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Elapsed time was " + (stopTime - startTime) + " miliseconds.");
```

Comment: My edit comment was "Fix method name "currentTimeMilis" -> "currentTimeMillis".  Makes code copy/pasteble.  (FWIW)"    But couldn't find 5 more chars to edit :(

Comment: I don't think that will work if, during your "Run some code", the machine is Windows 10 or greater and goes into S3 sleep during a Thread.sleep().  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394222/java-thread-sleep-on-windows-10-stops-in-s3-sleep-status

Answer (score 9):

Apache Commons-Lang also has the StopWatch class suited just for your purpose.  It uses System.currentTimeMillis(), so you'll still have resolution problems, but you can pause and do lap times and such.  I use it as standard now for event stats.

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html

Comment: Updated link: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html

Answer (score 8):

The [Answer by Leigh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/239661/642706) is correct.

## java.time

Java 8 and later has the java.time framework built in.

An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC with nanosecond resolution (up to 9 digits of a decimal fraction of a second). The [`now`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--) method grabs the current date-time moment.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

> 2016-03-12T04:29:39.123Z

You can calculate the elapsed time between a pair of `Instant` objects as a [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). The duration uses nanosecond resolution with a maximum value of the seconds that can be held in a long. This is greater than the current estimated age of the universe.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( startInstant , stopInstant );
```

The default output of [`Duration::toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toString--) is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format. You can also ask for a total count of nanoseconds ([`toNanos`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toNanos--)) or milliseconds ([`toMillis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMillis--)), as well as other amounts.

### Java 8

In Java 8, fetching the current moment resolves only to millisecond resolution (up to 3 digits of a decimal fraction of a second). So while the java.time classes can *store* nanoseconds they can only determine the current moment with milliseconds. This limitation is due to a legacy issue (the default [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) implementation uses [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--)).

### Java 9

In Java 9 and later, the default `Clock` implementation can determine the current moment in up to nanosecond resolution. Actually doing so depends on the fineness of your computer’s clock hardware.

See this OpenJDK issue page for more info: [Increase the precision of the implementation of java.time.Clock.systemUTC()](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730)

## Micro Benchmark

If your purpose is benchmarking, be sure to look at other Questions such as:

- [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/642706)
- [Create quick/reliable benchmark with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6373550/642706)

Frameworks are available to assist with short-duration benchmarking.

Answer (score 5):

`java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()` or `java.lang.System.nanoTime()` ought to work to measure elapsed time.

Comment: Keep in mind that even though those functions return values that are measured in milliseconds and nanoseconds respectively, the clock resolution may not be that high.  A clock resolution of 15 ms is pretty common -- keep that in mind when timing very short events.

Comment: I have good experience with LockSupport.parkNanos() on Windows in terms of resolution - but that's not a candidate for a stopwatch for this question I admit.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small StopWatch class I wrote using the System.nanoTime() as suggested in the answer from Leigh:

```
public class StopWatch {
    // Constructor
    public StopWatch() {
    }

    // Public API
    public void start() {
        if (!_isRunning) {
            _startTime = System.nanoTime();
            _isRunning = true;
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (_isRunning) {
            _elapsedTime += System.nanoTime() - _startTime;
            _isRunning = false;
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        _elapsedTime = 0;
        if (_isRunning) {
            _startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return _isRunning;
    }

    public long getElapsedTimeNanos() {
        if (_isRunning) {
            return System.nanoTime() - _startTime;
        }
        return _elapsedTime;
    }

    public long getElapsedTimeMillis() {
        return getElapsedTimeNanos() / 1000000L;
    }

    // Private Members
    private boolean _isRunning = false;
    private long _startTime = 0;
    private long _elapsedTime = 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding convenience methods for getting seconds value and a constructor with boolean flag which will allow the stopwatch to start immediately. At least that's what I needed, after I used your class:)