# Is there a Java library for calculating elapsed time?

Tags: java, time

I am wondering if there is a library one can use that calculates elapsed time? Something like... if you pass it a `long` of milliseconds, you get a result like "2d 5h 12m 55s" (possibly even more formats similarly to `SimpleDateFormatter`).

I've heard of jodatime, but I've never used it. Can it be used for such calculations, or are there other more appropriate libraries?

It's not like I can't knock up a few methods myself, but I find myself doing this every now and then and that's why I'm wondering if something like this already exists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java

Comment: I believe that the answer you are looking for is in this ancient post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567659/calculate-elapsed-time-in-java-groovy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate the elapsed time of an event in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238920/how-do-i-calculate-the-elapsed-time-of-an-event-in-java)

Comment: @SteveChambers That question doesn't cover converting the elapsed time to days, hours, minutes, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)'s [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Period.html) & [PeriodFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html). [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179644/how-to-calculate-elapsed-time-from-now-with-joda-time).