# How to get exec/fetch time of a JDBC query?

Tags: java, database, performance, jdbc, time

Tools like the [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com) typically display an exec/fetch time after executing a database query. Is it possible to access such performance metrics after executing a query through JDBC?

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

// missing functionality:
float executionTime = rsmd.getExecTime();
float fetchTime = rsmd.getFetchTime();
```

I did not find any such performance measure functionality in either the `ResultSet` or `ResultSetMetaData` classes. Is there no better way than 'manually' measuring the elapsed time using the system clock as discussed for example in [How do I calculate the elapsed time of an event in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238920/how-do-i-calculate-the-elapsed-time-of-an-event-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to measure the timing. Usually you would time things in **milli-seconds** with `System.currentTimeMillis()` or use `System.nanoTime()` for greater resolution/accuracy.

It would be a waste for it to time this automatically when it is rarely used.

Answer (score 0):

Sormula ORM can log timing information.

```
description=SELECT id, firstName, lastName, graduationDate FROM Student WHERE id IN (?, ?)
prepare    = 50% 00:00:00.000382423 n=  1 avg=00:00:00.000382423
write      =  7% 00:00:00.000054496 n=  1 avg=00:00:00.000054496
execute    = 25% 00:00:00.000190143 n=  1 avg=00:00:00.000190143
read       = 19% 00:00:00.000144009 n=  2 avg=00:00:00.000072005
total      =100% 00:00:00.000771071
```

See [timing example](http://sormula.org/timing/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `log4jdbc` library to log all JDBC connections, please refer the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988231/how-to-log-jdbc-connection-activity) and [log4jdbc repository](https://github.com/arthurblake/log4jdbc) for more information