# How to create a functionality that will measure time the start, end and execution time of the query in java?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, log4j, benchmarking

Good afternoon! I need to create functionality that would allow me to measure the start/end time and duration of the query. I tried using the log4j library and creating my own logger, but I can't specify it in applicationSpringContext. Maybe someone could advise how to approach this issue correctly ? And what tools could I use for such tasks? Thank you very much for your help!
MyLogger:

```
package net.proselyte.springbootdemo;

import org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

public class NewStatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener extends StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(NewStatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener.class);

    @Override
    public void jdbcExecuteStatementStart() {
        //Write method
    }

    @Override
    public void jdbcPrepareStatementEnd() {
        //Write method
    }
}
```

MyApplicationContext when i try to add:

```
logging.level.net.proselyte.springbootdemo.NewStatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener=info
```

my task should have this output :

```
startTime=2020-09-18 Time 10:30:1231
endTime=2020-09-18 Time 10:30:2500
requestExecutionTime=60;
success/unsuccess
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Some JDBC call
long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeElapsed = finish - start;
```

Comment: there are many methods, and if I call start() stop () on each one, it will take a long time. I need a universal option

Comment: I have seen technologies like New Relic which can do that but here's a library called " log4jdbc". You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988231/how-to-log-jdbc-connection-activity)