# How can I log SQL query times in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

If I configure Log4j2 using `<Logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core" level="ALL"/>` I will see all SQL queries going on, but I have no idea how long these queries take.

Is there an easy way of hooking into the Hikari pool to show timings or do some built-in Spring config magic?

I have used Jdbi3 in the past (which is far more pleasurable than Spring JDBC) and it has a nice API for just this: [SqlLogger](https://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/core/statement/SqlLogger.html) that you can use to log pre/post any query. That means you can implement it and use log4j's `isDebugEnabled()` to selectively enable and disable timing.

I have seen [the Hikari docs point to p6spy](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/57#issuecomment-354647631), but that is an external solution to a problem I feel should have a built-in solution :)

I did give it a half-assed try to implement a log writer:

```
@PostConstruct
public void setLogLevel() {
    final var logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("no.bring.notifications.engine.JdbcStatements");

    try {
        dataSource.setLogWriter(new PrintWriter(System.out) {
            
            @Override
            public void println(String x) {
                // Log to Log4j2 instead of System.out
                logger.warn(x);
            }
        });
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("Error setting log writer", e);
    }
```

Although it is created, the method I overrode never seem to be called, so ... I cannot bother to implement all the methods to see if it works.

Comment: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215564/how-to-get-exec-fetch-time-of-a-jdbc-query) seems relevant.  One option would be to benchmark the queries directly from your Java code.

Comment: It's exactly that manual work/code I would like to avoid. JDBI has a beautiful API for doing just this: https://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/core/statement/SqlLogger.html