# Android background loop doesn't run at fixed intervals

Tags: android

I have an app that writes some data to a file every second. 
I used a `Timer` that and schedule it at a fixed interval of 1000
for the most part it works fine, but sometimes i notice there are seconds, or sometime even minutes where there is no data in the log file.

Is there any likely suspects to this problem?

Comment: Please post some code so we can take a look at what you've done so far.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Timer will automatically tick every 1000 milliseconds or 1 sec. Please post some code along with logcat output.

Comment: are you using a thread? like a game-loop? if you are you should just use deltaTime instead of the timer function

Answer (score 0):

Timer runs in background thread(s) that are not reliable. From the docs:

Each timer has one thread on which tasks are executed sequentially. When this thread is busy running a task, runnable tasks may be subject to delays.

LINK: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

If you have a time sensitive task, then you need to check SystemClock like here:

[How to measure elapsed time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248891/how-to-count-elapsed-time)